# What is the meaning of "ToBooleanLogicalNot" in V8 byte code?

Tags: v8

I'm analyzing V8 byte code which I got from some applications and saw "ToBooleanLogicalNot".
What's the meaning of it?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I guess that it inverts the accumulator's value to a logical type. but not 100% sure.

Comment: Based on https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e6f7a3470f5798c6fe01a2bb88ae0c2ce46b5ce6/src/interpreter/interpreter-generator.cc#L1225 "Perform logical-not on the accumulator, first casting the accumulator to a boolean value if required."

Answer (score 0):

It means "Perform logical-not on the accumulator".

from Nodejs source code

[image]

this is a sample JavaScript code.

[image]

this is a corresponding V8 byte code.

[image]

Thank you all.